# Filter a tibble with two conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

i have this tibble..

```
tibble(id=c(4,4), client=c(5,10), stock=c(NA,10))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
     id client stock
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4      5    NA
2     4     10    10
```

from which i want to keep the row where client == 5 and stock == 10. How would i filter that? So my desired outcome would be:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
      a client stock
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4      5    10
```

Comment: There is no row where client == 5 and stock == 10 in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the context of filtering using values from different rows, but see if below operation works for you.

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% fill(stock, .direction = 'up') %>% filter(client == 5 & stock == 10)
# A tibble: 1 x 3
     id client stock
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4      5    10
```